# Cómo cargar información asíncrona antes de instanciar la ventana WPF en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy consumiendo una API con HTTPClient de manera asíncrona de cuyo contenido necesito disponer antes de instanciar la ventana principal. He cambiado el método Main de la clase App a async para poder ejecutar el método Connection que me devuelve un List. Algo así:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "7.0.5.0")]
    public async static Task Main() {
        Elements = await Connection();
        if(Elements.Count!=0) { 
            Ventana.App app = new Ventana.App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo instanciar la aplicación");
        }
    }
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto este código me devuelve este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que es porque estoy manipulando el hilo principal a través de la asincronía, pero ni sé solucionarlo ni sé si estoy aplicando el mejor procedimiento para obtener el resultado que quiero.

Básicamente la API me devuelve todos los elementos de la tabla periódica de los elementos. En "Elements" los almaceno para disponer de ellos en la vista y poder generar dinámicamente componentes con la distribución de la tabla. Para ello necesito solucionar este asunto de la asincronía. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Saca el `async` dejando el main como debe ser `public static void Main()` y luego cambias esto `Elements = await Connection();` por esto `Task.Run( async () => Elements = await Connection()).Wait();`

Comment: La otra opcion, es que hagas esto al cargar la pantalla realmente, porque por mas que sea async, nadie se va a enterar que algo esta pasando, y no es la idea, no_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo solucioné así. Con esto consigo cargar la lista de elementos antes de iniciar la ventana. Luego genero la vista sin problema.

```
 private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        elementos = await Connection();
        Trace.WriteLine(elementos.Count.ToString());

        if (elementos.Count != 0)
        {
            MainWindow w=new MainWindow();
            w.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido un error en la recuperación de datos");
        }

        //base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```